# is it possible to using index in unix datetime colum in MySQL 5.7 when using function

Tags: mysql

is it possible to using index in unix datetime colum in MySQL 5.7? I define my database table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_envelope_app_list` (
  `created_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
)
```

the `created_time` store unix timestamp,now this is my SQL:

```
 select max(user_id) as user_id
 from report_user
 group by user_id, date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

but now the colum `created_time` contains function and could not using the index, is it possbible to using index, I have to add a column to store date like `%Y-%m-%d`? I tried to add a generated column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
ADD COLUMN statistic_date varchar(16) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d') STORED;
```

but failed.

Comment: `date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')` could go into a `DATE` column

Comment: Do you really want to both `GROUP BY user_id` _and` `SELECT MAX(user_id)`??

Answer (score 1):

using generate column and created a index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE report_user 
ADD COLUMN statistic_date varchar(16) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(statistic_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d')) STORED;
```

then created index:

```
CREATE INDEX report_user_userid_staticdate_idx 
ON report_user(user_id,statistic_date);
```

Comment: ... then use this generated column in the query instead of the expression.